# Save boolean data by use AsyncStorage in redux

Tags: javascript, java, android, ios, react-native

I want to set state "true" or "false" when click a button, and save it by using AsyncStorage in react native with redux. 
Did I do correctly ? Please help me fix it.

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import {
  START_TOOLTIP_BUDGET,
  STOP_TOOLTIP_BUDGET
} from "../actions/ActionTypes";

const INIT_STATE = true;
export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case START_TOOLTIP_BUDGET:
      AsyncStorage.setItem("INIT_STATE", JSON.stringify(true));
      return INIT_STATE;

    case STOP_TOOLTIP_BUDGET:
      AsyncStorage.setItem("INIT_STATE", JSON.stringify(false));
      return INIT_STATE;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it correctly but if yo return INIT_STATE true or false, you can get current data for your current class. Otherwise you return true every time.

```
export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case START_TOOLTIP_BUDGET:
      AsyncStorage.setItem("INIT_STATE", JSON.stringify(true));
      return true;

    case STOP_TOOLTIP_BUDGET:
      AsyncStorage.setItem("INIT_STATE", JSON.stringify(false));
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And than get it from class that click the button. And also you can get the AsyncStorage item;

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("INIT_STATE")
    .then(req => JSON.parse(req))
    .then(data => {
        if (data !== null) { 
          console.log(data); // true or false 
        }
    }).done();
```